# Renaming the tag "schengen-visa" to "schengen-visas"

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-renaming

Currently the tag is named [schengen-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen-visa) but all (most) of the other visa tags are named visa**s**.

Shouldn't the Schengen Visas tag be named [schengen-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen-visas)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag [has been renamed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51354706#51354706).