# Shengen-visa and Schengen-visas tags

Tags: discussion

Why do we have two tags: one for Schengen-visa, and another for Schengen-visas? The latter is used far more often than the former.

Wouldn't a single tag suffice?

EDIT: This topic has already appeared [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/renaming-the-tag-schengen-visa-to-schengen-visas).

I suggest we agree to disappear the "Shengen-visa" tag.

Comment: It only got switched a few hours ago, and some pending edits hadn't taken effect yet. Should only be schengen-visas. If you see any of the singular form remaining, please edit the question or flag it if unable. Thanks!

Comment: Very good, makes sense to me. Thanks.